# Woocommerce product page not showing products platform wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqtdh.png)I am facing issue with the products in woocommerce. showing in the backend. Also in the home page products are showing but when click on a product not showing.
wordpress website.

Comment: Can you add more detail what to you mean by "not showing". Is this the initial state after install or it's old installation. Did you use other plugins, templates?

Comment: these is old installation

Comment: we have three categories in side bar, when i am clicking on sub categories its saying , no products are found.

Comment: But in products categories in back end its showing me counts

Comment: there is no option to send image otherwise i want to send the screenshot

Comment: You can add this additional information in your question and there is an option to upload image in the edit post screen. You can see the image icon above the text area.

Comment: i have added, its argent